# Image resizing using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-resizing

I am trying to make an image enlarge itself if a user clicks on it and retain its original size once the cursor is away from it, but the image is not responding, it's an 800 pixel image.

**behaviour.js**:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    alert('Hello!');
});

document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('I saw you click');
});

var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
thumbnailElement.className ="small";

if (thumbnailElement.className == "") {
    // write here the code that will execute if the image is big
}
```

**index.html**:

```
 <p>An 800 pixel image</p>
        <img id="smart_thumbnail"  src="http://calmground.com/wp-content/galler\
y/our-calm-ground/calm.jpg" class="small"  >
```

@kinglish,
I believe the `img.small` is a CSS code right, though I didn't copy your code, but I followed everything, seems something is breaking somewhere in my file because it's not running.

Index.html:

```
<p>An 800 pixel image</p>
                <img id='smart_thumbnail'  src='http://download.baps.org/wallpapers/14.bmp' class='small'  >
```

behavior.js I edited:

```
*document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   //  alert('Hello!');
});

document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function({
    var theElement = event.target;
    // to toggle class names
    if (theElement.classList.contains('small')) {

        theElement.classList.remove('small');
        theElement.classList.add('large');
    }else {
        theElement.classList.remove('large');
        theElement.classList.add('small');
    }

});
```

styles.css:

```
img.small {
    width: 50px;
}

img.large {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Your code shows no indication that the size of the image is changed whatsoever. If you do this by using a CSS class, you should put the code that changes the classes INSIDE the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to resize the image onClick and resize it again when out of hover:

```js
var enableHover = false;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    alert('Hello!');
});

document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('small');
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "An 800 pixel image";
    enableHover = true;
});

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  if (enableHover) {
    this.classList.toggle('small');
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "A 100 pixel image";
    enableHover = false;
  }
})
```

```css
.small {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p id="label">A 100 pixel image</p>
<img id="smart_thumbnail"  src="https://placekitten.com/400/800" class="small">
```

```html
<style>
  .small {
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>

<p id="label">A 100 pixel image</p>
<img id="smart_thumbnail" src="https://placekitten.com/400/800" class="small">

<script>
  var enableHover = false;
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    alert('Hello!');
  });

  document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

  var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

  thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('small');
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "An 800 pixel image";
    enableHover = true;
  });

  thumbnailElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    if (enableHover) {
      this.classList.toggle('small');
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "A 100 pixel image";
      enableHover = false;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I copied your code and I commented mine out to see the results, but its not even clicking not to talk of enlarging

Comment: Go copy the second code snippet. Its all the code you need

Comment: I did copied the code into my html file and it works, but am required to put the code in my behavior.js file but copying it there, it didn't work, but it displayed the javascript alert(Hello), is there any way I can work around this...

Comment: @Emmanuel Did you import the javascript in your header?  If so, put it just above the closing body tag.